# text file read in java to an object array

Tags: java, arrays

new to java
I have a text file like this and is called 'line'

```
abc   10,20,30     20,30,40    30,40,50
```

and the have code like this

```
  ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
  lines.add(line);
  Object[] lineContents = lines.toArray();
```

now I'm trying to get each element into a new array without the comma's

so my new array would look like

```
abc  10 20 30    20 30 40   30 40 50

object[] newlines = //update line text file
```

Comment: Well it looks like first you need to `.split(SPACE)` and then you need to do `.split(COMMA)` on the `1, 2, 3` elements of the array

Comment: Which type is `line` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a for loop over your array if `line` is of type `String`

```
Object[] newlines = new Object[lineContents.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < newlines.length ; i++) {
    newlines[i] = ((String)lineContents[i]).replace(",", " ");
}
```